# How to use latex function during sweave or knitr in R

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave

I would use rms::latex() function to generate nice tables and insert to x.rnw file so to print a fancy pdf file. But it seems not work well.

### Here is my chuncks:

```
Definition table
<<>>=
def[1,1]
@

Summary of date variables
<<>>=
date
@
```

### And the snapshot of the output pdf:

[image]

What I would like to is:

### Definition Table

BV_ENC_Infant Enrollment

### Summary of date variables

rms::latex(date)

Does anybody have some suggestions?

Comment: Thanks, baptiste! I rerun the chunk like `<<INI, echo=T, results='asis'>>=` but it shows an error of `Line 51 Missing $ inserted`? what's worng?

Comment: Guessing here. With results=asis, everything in the output will be parsed by LaTeX, so it needs to be valid LaTeX code. If you output or echo R code with $ symbols, LaTeX won't like it.